# Copy range from sheet, and loop through files in a directory and do the following, Add rows to specific sheet, and paste values into sheet

Tags: vba

I need to copy data from one sheet on my desktop, and paste it to every xlsx file in a specified folder. The problem I am encountering is an endless loop of copy paste / adding rows.

paste_value is the value to be pasted in the specified range in the specified sheet " Exhibit 1d"

Below is the code

```
Sub loopFile()
Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim paste_value As String


paste_value = Workbooks("copy_file.xlsx").Worksheets("EXHIBIT 1D").Range("B59:C64").Copy
Pathname = "C:\Users\GP8535\Desktop\loop_folder\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "\*.xls*")
Do While Filename <> ""
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    paste_value = Workbooks("copy_file.xlsx").Worksheets("EXHIBIT 1D").Range("B59:C64").Copy
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)

    wb.Worksheets("EXHIBIT 1D").Rows("57:63").EntireRow.Insert
    wb.Worksheets("EXHIBIT 1D").Range("B59:C63").PasteSpecial


    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True


Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. A few issues

- your syntax for defining `paste_value` was wrong; I think better to define the range (using Set) and do this outside the loop as it doesn't change
- key thing to loop through your files is the last line in the loop; your code would have opened the same workbook each time
- don't forget to turn alerts and updating back on at the end

  ```
  Sub loopFile()

  Dim Filename, Pathname As String
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim paste_value As Range

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Pathname = "C:\Users\GP8535\Desktop\loop_folder\"
  Filename = Dir(Pathname & "\*.xls*")
  Set paste_value = Workbooks("copy_file.xlsx").Worksheets("EXHIBIT 1D").Range("B59:C64")

  Do While Filename <> ""
     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
     wb.Worksheets("EXHIBIT 1D").Rows("57:63").EntireRow.Insert
     paste_value.Copy wb.Worksheets("EXHIBIT 1D").Range("B59:C63")
     wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
     Filename = Dir
  Loop

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Worked like a charm, can you explain what was the issue with my code?

Comment: Sure. I've added a few comments above.